# WSO2 claim configuration

Tags: wso2

I do my first steps with WSO2 (Version 5) and I do not understand the claim mapping.
Currently the travelocity.com application works fine. I can login and afterwards I'am redirected to the home page of the travelocity application - everything is fine.

No I would like the send different SAML assertions as response the the travelocity- appl.
Therefore I have added "Identity Provider Claim URIs" to the claim configuration (email and roles). 
What is not clear for me is, that there is only one select field "Subject Claim URI".
When I select the email URL, than in the SAML- Response is the following line:

```
<saml2:Subject>
        <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:name">email@email.com</saml2:NameID>
        <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
            <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="0"
                                           NotOnOrAfter="2014-08-30T09:18:56.447Z"
                                           Recipient="http://localhost:8080/travelocity.com/samlsso-home.jsp"
                                           />
        </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
    </saml2:Subject>
```

when I choose role- URL as Subject Claim URI, than I get the roles:

```
<saml2:Subject>
        <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:name">admin,xccx,asqs,Internal/identity,Internal/travelocity.com,Internal/everyone</saml2:NameID>
        <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
            <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="0"
                                           NotOnOrAfter="2014-08-30T09:18:56.447Z"
                                           Recipient="http://localhost:8080/travelocity.com/samlsso-home.jsp"
                                           />
        </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
    </saml2:Subject>
```

But I will get both in the SAML Response.

What I am doing wrong. 
Thanks a lot for any help and all the best!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Requested Claims to get claims in the SAMLAssertion. The subject claim is the username your application is expecting.

[image]